# Show that $x+y+xy>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $x,y\in ]-\infty,-2[$, show that $x+y+xy>0$.

I don’t know why this method doesn’t work,
$$\cases{x<-2 \\ y<-2 } \implies xy>4$$
and $$x+y<-4$$
But now I cant add them together, what should I do?

Comment: Set $x=-2-u$, $y = -2-v$ with $u, v \ge 0$ ...

Comment: $x+y+xy=(x+1)(y+1)-1$. For $x,y<-2$, $(x+1)<-1$ and $(y+1)<-1$ so $(x+1)(y+1)-1 > (-1)^2-1=0$.